# Is it safe to install LibreOffice alongside OpenOffice.org?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

I would like to try out LibreOffice, but I'm worried about messing up my existing OpenOffice.org install. Can LibreOffice be safely installed alongside OpenOffice.org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're installing [via the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16695/is-there-a-libreoffice-ppa) then no, it will replace OpenOffice.org with Libre Office.

If you're installing via the tarballs on their website, then tinhed's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14355/is-it-safe-to-install-libreoffice-alongside-openoffice-org/14419#14419) is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Yes absolutely. Considering you are using ubuntu and openoffice.org is installed by default, the libreoffice installer will install under the /opt directory thus not interfering with Oo installation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will be fine. it installs totally separate from OO

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even though LibreOffice is a fork of OpenOffice it is a completely standalone application and will install (and uninstall) without changing anything to do with Openoffice.