# Is there a PPA with the latest version of LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, software-installation

There was recently another release of [LibreOffice](http://www.documentfoundation.org/), but it is  a pain to have to manually go to their website and download the packages every time there is a new release. Is there a PPA that always has the latest version of LibreOffice?

Comment: Those who have already installed libreoffice-4.0 with the above mentioned ppa they will have to just run this command in the terminal $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade THIS WILL UPGRADE YOUR LIBREOFFICE 4.0 TO 4.1

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is an official LibreOffice PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa).

You need to add `ppa:libreoffice/ppa` in your software sources to add it to the software center, just follow the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) for the GUI way.

More information:

- [Is the ppa of LibreOffice to be considered safe for the system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52022/is-the-ppa-of-libreoffice-to-be-considered-safe-for-the-system)

To add ppa and upgrade libre office using command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This worked for me, although I did have to check for further upgrades to other packages that were "held back" after this. Running apt install <list of held back packages> fixed the issue.

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE 2**

As of July 25th 2013, the following PPA offers the Release version of LibreOffice:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That will leave you with LibreOffice 4.1.

---

**UPDATE 1**

A PPA is now available for 4.1.0.  To add it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
```

For complete instructions on how to install the beta2 of Libreoffice 4.1.0, check out [LibreOffice Pre-Releases](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-prereleases)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I have searched high and low, and I can't find a PPA for 4.1.x.  Now if you would like to install it, (the documentation doesn't mention removing prior installation) I would recommend that you remove previous versions before installing this one.

To install LibreOffice 4.1.0 Beta 1 on Ubuntu 13.04, 12.10, and 12.04, do this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

For 32 bit systems:

```
wget -c dev-builds.libreoffice.org/pre-releases/deb/x86/LibreOfficeDev_4.1.0.0.beta1_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz
```

For 64 bit systems:

```
wget -c dev-builds.libreoffice.org/pre-releases/deb/x86_64/LibreOfficeDev_4.1.0.0.beta1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
```

Extract the archive:

```
eDev_4.1.0.tar -zxvf LibreOffic0.beta1_Linux_x86*_deb.tar.gz
```

Install LibreOffice 4.1.0:

```
cd LibreOfficeDev*/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *
```

As of June 13, 2013 it still not available in the [pre-release PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-prereleases).  Once available will update the answer.

<sup>Source:LinuxG</sup>

Comment: It's time to upkeep this great answer and sort the updates made to it by decresing time order. I mean: Put first "As of july 25 ...".

Comment: i had to do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead of just `update`. 
See this [Server fault answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/46748/can-someone-clarify-ubuntu-debian-dist-upgrade-for-me/46749#46749) for better explanation of `dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 6):

The [main LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) is for "test builds and backports", including "alpha and beta releases!".
**UPDATE** As of 2016-07, I see it's "LibreOffice fresh", the latest release of the newest series (but no alpha/beta releases, which are now in separate PPA).

If you want less-bleeding edge, it includes links to per-version stable PPAs, e.g. https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-1 for LibreOffice 4.1.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use a Pre-Release (Alpha, Beta or Pre-Release version) you can use the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will give you the latest Pre-Release version available. It works perfectly with LibreOffice 4.2.x (At this moment). If you get any problems related to broken packages or the likes you can force the upgrade procedure which fixes any related problems with the already installed packages. In the case however I would recommend using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` (For a better dependency resolver) like this:

```
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

Of course this is only in the worst case scenario but always remember to read the recommendations of aptitude before proceeding which mentions which packages will be removed, upgraded and installed.