# LibreOffice RC1 deb package difficulties

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, deb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

I seem to be running into some difficulties with the acquisition of the latest libreoffice deb pkg.

When I type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get

```
E: Malformed line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist) E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I don't understand of that means that I did something wrong or if there is a problem at tuxfamily.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated.

[Full contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/544110)

Comment: Post your output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: karthick87 -the actual output was over the posting limit by some 2300 characters.  This is the last line (which I thought might be helpful).
<deb hxxp://download.tuxfamily.org/gericom/libreoffice/>

Comment: @Beachbuddah Throw it up on http://pastebin.ubuntu.com that'll be easier.

Comment: ok here goes:   pastebin.ubuntu.com/544110

Comment: Hate to say this but RC3 was released yesterday

Comment: You need to have something after the URL; I don't know what.  I'd go ahead and just add ppa:libreoffice/ppa, as Jorge said below.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just install LO from the PPA: [Is there a PPA with the latest version of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16695/is-there-a-libreoffice-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Change hxxp to http

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hxxp

Comment: Have you added the key? http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@documentfoundation.org/msg00512.html

Comment: I removed and re-added the repository and when I did, I fixed an earlier problem (I was temporarily blocked from updating my system) but got a new message: "W: Failed to fetch http://download.tuxfamily.org/gericom/libreoffice/Release  Unable to find expected entry  Sources in Meta-index file (malformed Release file?)".  While I was in the software sources GUI, I checked and the key was there but either I added the repo incorrectly (copied n pasted) or the target is missing.

Comment: @Beachbuddah follow @Jorge Castro's answer.