# What is the way to get the latest version of LibreOffice?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, libreoffice

Should one use the PPA or manually install the `.deb`s from http://www.libreoffice.org?

Is there any difference between the two? How long does it take for the ppa to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a PPA with the latest version of LibreOffice?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16695/is-there-a-ppa-with-the-latest-version-of-libreoffice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PPAs provide a new source of software for Ubuntu.

They are updated to the newest version seen as stable with your system. They will list updates much like normal ones in the Update Manager (unlike .Debs), and the admin of the PPA should not list the most recent version to sent to older systems if it is incompatible.

.Debs provide none of these protections.

Because of that, and that the installation of LibreOffice with .Deb packages requires the download and extraction of several .Tar.gz archives and subsequent installations, I would recommend using the PPA, in the Terminal if possible (far faster).

Unfortunately, the PPA is only for [currently supported versions of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life).

To add the PPA, update the Software Sources, and update/install just libreoffice, execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

If you want to continue using the latest version tested (stable) for you, just run the Update Manager, check for updates, and install them regularly.

Comment: why is there no ppa for 11.10?

Comment: I don't know, that PPA doesn't have anything listed for Oneiric (11.10). It is whoever maintains the PPAs decision as to what versions (of libreoffice) are sent out to what versions (of ubuntu).

Comment: This answer has now become out-of-date.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I've done my best both to update it, and to make it more version agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

there are no difference man you can use anyone only different that software download and install from something like ubuntu software center and repository are purport and easier for beginner user like to download and install without face any problem me and other thing no difference

and about libre office man you can you download it from main site (download deb files because you use debian Distribution) and after that use this command with it sudo tar -xvf (name of download files) if it comperessd with tar.gz

or use directly sudo dpkg -i (name of download files) if it download with deb extenison sorry i didn't download it before so i don't know any of that will be downloaded

or best thing to download and install it automatic from ubuntu software center and write in search libreoffice and choose libreoffice writer and press more info and choose all add-ons and then install

you can follow this link to install libreoffice from terminal if you want that

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/libreoffice

latest verison for libreoffice yet is 3.5.0 from main site

Answer (score 0):

The problem with PPA's is that those depends on their package maintainers which could also be third parties. I would download the official package in the [Document Fundation download page](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-stable/) and installing it with `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/tdf/libreoffice/stable/4.1.6/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_4.1.6_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
## This link can change, is the 64-bit version for 4.1.6
tar xf LibreOffice*_deb.tar.gz
cd LibreOffice*
gdebi *.deb
```

Of course, there are more packages than what you would need, so just installing them by order is necesary.