# LibreOffice Snap Store Update

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice latest/stable 7.5.3.2 (2 May 2023) is available in Snap but is not offered as an update in Ubuntu 22.04.02 ? What would be the correct way of manually updating? The reason for my question is that a while ago I installed LO 7.5.[I can't remember] from the Snap Store and it was horribly slow on a beefy Ubuntu 22.04 box, and I don't want to mess up my current setup. Interestingly though the latest version of LO I installed on a new Arch Cinnamon VM in Boxes runs flawlessly... I recon uninstalling the current version and then installing the new version using apt makes the most sense, but should I maybe update Java too?

Comment: You don't need to manually update Java

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Snap apps are horribly slow unless you have a fast SSD. Also, there are [reasons](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283/124466) why Ubuntu does not update software in its official repositories. The workaround is to use the LibreOffice PPA. See [Is there a PPA with the latest version of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16695/124466)

Comment: Should I uninstall LO current version before adding the PPA and upgrading? I don't want to end up with two versions of LO...

Comment: You can remove the snap version, if installed, add the PPA, and `sudo apt install libreoffice libreoffice-gtk3`

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE (09 June 2023):

Just found an alternative solution and it works great. Can download and run LO Latest Version as an AppImage.

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/appimage/

@Archisman Panigrahi - Thank you for your assistance and the links. Adding the PPA seems to be the best way to go. The only reasons I want to update is to get Tabbed View and Dark Mode. But I will do a CloneZilla SaveImage first just in case. Ironically the Snap Store offered a LO update a few hours ago, but same as currently installed version, it's just a security update...

> Version: 7.3.7.2 / LibreOffice Community Build ID: 30(Build:2) Ubuntu
> package version: 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3